# No "word break", change the length of cvitem

Tags: moderncv

I use the classic template of moderncv.
And I want to make the cvitem name(marked with red) not broken, and I don't want to change the font size, just want to make the item name longer.
[image]

I have search several times and not found the solution. Does anyone came up with this problem before? I'm so appreciate your help.

best regards,
Melo

Comment: If you don't want to change the font size, how do you expect it to fit without breaking? Have it protrude to the left / to the right, or increase the length of the “column” throughout the document, or… ?

Comment: Also: welcome to tex.stackexchange.com :-) Please include a complete, minimal, compilable file (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) which highlights the issue, so that there is something concrete to play with. You can remove sections that are not relevant, change the names if anything is sensitive, etc., to make it minimal.

Comment: sorry, this is my first post here, for me it's still too much to learn about the community. Thank you for your advice. The tex file is the template from the CTAN package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classic`style of `moderncv` uses two columns to layout the cv. The first column takes the rule of command `\section`, the second column takes the text.

To change the length of the first column you can use command

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
```

and change my `3cm` as you need ...

To get german umlauts in your document please add

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

to your code.

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy; head 3, body 3
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % <=========================================

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{Max}{Mustermann}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{max.mustermann@email.de}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % <==================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Persönliche Daten}
\cvitem{Geburtsdatum}{26.04.1089 in China}
\cvitem{Staatsangehörigkeit}{chinesisch}
\cvitem{Familienstand}{ledig}

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I need.  Bother you one more, if you know how to make the name in English and Chinese in two lines, that would be awesome. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}` in your preamble (you can adjust the length to your needs) should solve this problem.